# A common JSON Schema for similar structure

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm completely new to json and json schema, so I have a question (yet I don't know how much it make sense). Can we create a json schema which is common for similar type of structure. For example:

One single schema can be used to validate following json

JSON:

```
{
"Team_Table":
[{"Name":"New Zealand", "Match":"Six", "Won":"Six"}]
}
```

And

```
{
"Story_Taller":
[{"Story":"No Name", "Chapter":"Don't know"}]
}
```

Similarities:

1. Both have only one object in the array
2. Objects have string value.

Dissimilarities:

1. Number of properties are different
2. Keys are different in both

Can we do this?

Comment: Please add comment while up or down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you along:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "Story_Taller": {
      "type": "array",
      "maxItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "properties": {
          "Chapter": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Story": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    },
    "Team_Table": {
      "type": "array",
      "maxItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "properties": {
          "Name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Match": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Won": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "title": "Story_Taller",
      "required": [
        "Story_Taller"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Team_Table",
      "required": [
        "Team_Table"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

in (short) words:

> in your JSON there must be one property of either "Story_Taller" or "Team_Table" with a maximum of 1 item

```
"oneOf": [ ... ]
```

> Properties of both arrays are defined by items

"Story_Taller" must have "Chapter" and "Story" and no additional properties.
"Team_Table" must have "Name", "Match", "Won" and no additional properties.
And all of them are defined as strings.